# GPL-3.0が適応される範囲、条件についてお聞きします。

Tags: ライセンス

GPL-3.0が適用されているOSSが生成したそのソフト独自の拡張子のファイルを
自作のソフトで読み取りを行った場合、自作のソフトもGPL-3.0を適用しなければならないのでしょうか？

[image: 1]

また、独自の拡張子のファイルを変換するソフトをオープンソースで作り
そのソフトが書き出したファイルをメインの自作ソフトで読み書きする場合、メインの自作ソフトはClosedSourceにすることはできますか？

[image: 2]

ご回答頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 下記の回答は素人がリンク先の参考資料を読んだ考察です。専門家の意見ではありませんのでご注意ください

一部の例外を除きGPL-3.0を適用する必要はありません。

[GPLプログラムの出力結果もGPLが及ぶのは、どんな場合ですか?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#WhatCaseIsOutputGPL)
上記の翻訳サイトを引用します。

> プログラムの出力は、一般的に、プログラムのコードに対する著作権でカバーされません。ですから、プログラムのコードのライセンスはその出力には及びません。ファイルへパイプ出力する、スクリーンショットを取る、スクリーンを放映する、ビデオに撮るにしろ、なんにしろです。
> 例外は、プログラムがプログラムについてくるテキストや芸術作品のフルスクリーンを表示する場合でしょう。この場合、テキストや芸術作品の著作権が出力に及びます。音楽を出力するビデオゲームのようなプログラムも、この例外にあたるでしょう。

後半の段落を広義に解釈すると「GPLプログラム(以下、OSSと書きます)」独自の出力はプログラムに付いてくるテキストではないか」と思う人もいるかもしれませんが、後半を素直に読み解くと「GPLで公開されているゲームのムービーシーンやノベルゲームのテキストを抽出してGPL以外で公開してはならない」と解します。
実際に次の行でそのことを明言しています。

> 芸術作品/音楽がGPLである場合、どのようにコピーするかに関わらず、コピーした際にGPLは適用されます。しかしながら、フェアユースは、なお、適用されます。

OSSに同封されている著作権の記述の中で出力するファイルについて明言されていない限りは出力ファイルにGPLライセンスは適用されないと考えます。
「OSS独自ファイルのバイナリ/テキストはフルスクリーンで表示するための芸術作品だ」と訴訟するのは無理筋のケースが多いのではないでしょうか。

また一部の例外として、OSS独自の出力ファイルにGPLのソースコードやプログラム自体を含む場合もGPLライセンスが適用されます。
こちらは下記を引用します。

[自由でないプログラムを開発するために、GNU EmacsのようなGPLの及ぶエディタを使っても良いでしょうか? GCCのようなGPLの及ぶツールを使って自由でないプログラムをコンパイルすることはできますか?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF)

> プログラムによっては、技術的な都合から自身の一部を出力結果にコピーするものがあります。たとえば、Bisonは標準パーザ・プログラムを出力ファイルにコピーします。そのような場合、出力結果にコピーされたテキストはそのソースコードに及ぶものと同じライセンスによってライセンスされます。一方、プログラムに与えられた入力から派生した出力結果の一部は入力側の著作権状態を継承します。

つまり出力ファイル自体が「プログラム自体のバイナリを含む」場合や「ソースコードそのものを含む」場合はGPLを継承すると考えます。
「これはOSSのソースコードと同一のソースコードを**偶然**プロプライエタリのプログラムが出力したものだからセーフ」という理論は通りません。

> また、独自の拡張子のファイルを変換するソフトをオープンソースで作り
> そのソフトが書き出したファイルをメインの自作ソフトで読み書きする場合、メインの自作ソフトはClosedSourceにすることはできますか？

この回答には踏み台のOSSを作った場合の取り扱いを完全には含みません。
踏み台のソフトウェアはGPLを継承している以上、メインの自作ソフトがその出力ファイルを扱うときのライセンスは元のOSSの出力ファイルを扱う時のライセンスに準じるはずです。
例えば自作ソフトのjsonがOSSの出力ファイルに含まれるGPLのソースコードをすべて含む場合はGPLを継承すると考えます。

最後に、出力ファイルが芸術作品か判断できない場合やプログラムやソースコードが含まれているか分からない場合は、ご自身でソースコードを確認するか公開している人に確認するのが確実な方法です。
しかしGPLは何でもかんでも適用されるものではないライセンスであることを把握して第三者にも説明できることは良いことだと思います。

参考資料：
[Does "the GPL doesn't cover the ouput of a program" also apply if the output is source code?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/8058)
[Licensing of content created by licensed code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/278285)
[Using output of GNU GPL software in commercial purposes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/311084)